# Why md5($string) != $string in php?

Tags: php, md5

I am having a problem with the md5() function. I was playing around with this function. But I am stuck at a point.

```
<?php

    $name = 'Taif';

    if (md5($name) == $name){
        echo 'True';
    }   else{
        echo 'False';
    }

?>
```

Why is it printing out False?

Comment: Echo `md5($name)` and you will find out why.

Comment: What do you think `md5` does? It's a hashing algorithm, the output is never going to be the same as the input.

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)

Comment: Don't use md5. Unless you are... well no.. can't think of any reason to use it. Just don't.

Comment: guys, its a trick question, y'all got triggered lol, the OP though this was reddit

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the value of `$name` is "Taif" while the value of `md5($name)` is "40f245f002555c4a6105d6066d2bdb85"

So it is impossible for it to return "True" because they are totally different values.

> MD5: `string md5 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = FALSE ] )`
>
> Calculates the MD5 hash of str using the [» RSA Data Security, Inc.
>   MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1321), and returns that hash.

Answer (score -1):

md5() is a php function used to encrypt plain texts. For example: converting a plain text(ie. password) into encrypted text .

Comment: 1: encryption != hashing 2: **never** use plain `md5()` to hash passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson guys , made lots of mistakes in the early coding days and still do.